# Describe the graphs linear association between these two variables height and width

Tags: data-visualization, linear, graph-theory, association-measure

I have written the code below to create a scatterplot to visualize whether the two variables are linearly associated but I am not sure how you would describe this output. I would say it is not linearly associated but I am not sure as the data are so spread apart. Also, are the data in the corner possible outliers? Can anyone please advise.

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
library("ggpubr")

ggscatter(file, x = "height", y = "width", add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, 
cor.method = "pearson", xlab = "height", ylab = "width")
```

[image: Graph Output]

Comment: The scatterplot strongly indicates your data do not conform to several key assumptions needed to justify the least squares fit.  You might find it helpful to review our threads on linear regression assumptions and diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

You have fit a straight line to the data. That line doesn't seem to depict the relationship very well. This is not because the data are "spread out" but because the relationship isn't linear.

You could try fitting a restricted cubic spline or loess curve to the data, the resulting lines might give you a better sense of the relationship.

The points in the lower right might come from some other population, or they might not. It's hard to say just from the plot. However, without those points, it looks like there is almost no relationship at all.